# In Android How to setvalue according to edittext fields

Tags: android

In my android I have the xml file :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/liner" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/partner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I have a string i.e **String field =error.getmethod();**
This string(field) may return user/name/partner/home..
I want to set error message according to edittext fields with their id's..I have done

```
 ViewGroup edittextviews = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.liner);
                    for(int i=0; i < edittextviews.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View childView = edittextviews.getChildAt(i);
                    if(childView.getText().toString()==field ){
                        childView.setError("here is an error");

                    }

                    }
```

But it is showing error...where is the problem???

Comment: This thing is not for compareing..

Comment: But it is. You compare your strings using `==` when you should use  `.equals()`. The latter checks the contents of the strings while the first checks for object equality which is not the same. Blackbelt is right.